# How can I run a windows batch file but hide the command window?

Tags: windows, scripting, batch-file

How can I run a windows batch file but hiding the command window? I dont want cmd.exe to be visible on screen when the file is being executed. Is this possible?

Comment: How are you launching?  via code?  just running in windows?  via some other script?

Comment: They are Windows shell scripts being invoked by a desktop app

Comment: What language is this application written in?

Comment: It is an application server - a Windows executable running on Windows Server 2003

Comment: What kind of control do you have over the server application? Do you own the source code (can modify it and recompile?) If you do not have control over the application's source, to what lengths are you willing to go to achieve your goal, are you willing to write e.g. C++ code to inject into the application at runtime in order to intercept `CreateProcess` and alter its `dwCreationFlags` parameter on the fly as to spawn (certain) children in hidden or minimized mode etc.?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If you write an **unmanaged program** and use [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa) API then you should initialize `lpStartupInfo` parameter of the type [STARTUPINFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-startupinfoa) so that `wShowWindow` field of the struct is [SW_HIDE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-showwindow) and not forget to use `STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW` flag in the `dwFlags` field of [STARTUPINFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-startupinfoa). Another method is to use [CREATE_NO_WINDOW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/process-creation-flags) flag of `dwCreationFlags` parameter. The same trick work also with [ShellExecute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecutea) and [ShellExecuteEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecuteexa) functions.

If you write a **managed application** you should follows advices from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2006/09/28/createnowindow.aspx: initialize `ProcessStartInfo` with `CreateNoWindow = true` and `UseShellExecute = false` and then use as a parameter of . Exactly like in case of you can set property `WindowStyle` of `ProcessStartInfo` to `ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden` instead or together with `CreateNoWindow = true`.

You **can use a VBS script** which you start with wcsript.exe. Inside the script you can use `CreateObject("WScript.Shell")` and then [Run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//d5fk67ky%28v=vs.85%29) with 0 as the second (`intWindowStyle`) parameter. See http://www.robvanderwoude.com/files/runnhide_vbs.txt as an example. I can continue with Kix, [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//dd347667%28v=technet.10%29) and so on.

If you don't want to write any program you can use **any existing utility** like [CMDOW /RUN /HID "c:\SomeDir\MyBatch.cmd"](https://web.archive.org/web/20160611122141/http://www.commandline.co.uk/cmdow/), [hstart /NOWINDOW /D=c:\scripts "c:\scripts\mybatch.bat"](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/hide-flashing-command-line-and-batch-file-windows-on-startup/), [hstart /NOCONSOLE "batch_file_1.bat"](https://www.ntwind.com/software/hstart.html)  which do exactly the same. I am sure that you will find much more such kind of free utilities.

In some scenario (for example *starting from UNC path*) it is important to set also a **working directory** to some local path (`%SystemRoot%\system32` work always). This can be important for usage any from above listed variants of starting hidden batch.

Comment: So is it possible for a batch file to hide its own window?

Comment: @KyleDelaney: Yes, it's possible, but I'm not sure which tool would be better to recommend you. It's easier for me to write the corresponding utility myself as to find existing one. Sorry, the answer is very old and some links (like the link on cmdow is changed now. You can find it on https://ritchielawrence.github.io/cmdow/). I want to stress that it's easier (and more safe) *to start* the batch hidden with respect of some utility and to hide the window from the batch which is already started.

Answer (score 8):

Using C# it's very easy to start a batch command without having a window open.
Have a look at the following code example:

```
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "doSomeBatch.bat";
        process.Start();
```

Answer (score 6):

For any executable file, you can run your program using cmd with "c" parameter:

```
cmd /c "your program address"\"YourFileName".bat
```

(->if it's a batch file!) As a final solution, I suggest that you create a .cmd file and put this command in it:

```
cmd /c "your program address"\"YourFileName".bat
exit
```

Now just run this .cmd file.

Comment: So, it opens up a command window, that fires up a bat without a window?

Comment: The command prompt window is hidden, because of the "c" parameter, and after the execution, command prompt will be closed, and during execution it does not show any symptom that the command prompt is running, even if you run command prompt, it will run in a visible form, and I haven't met any problem yet.

Answer (score 3):

Native C++ codified version of Oleg's answer -- this is copy/pasted from [a project I work on](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/combofix/how-to-use-combofix) under the Boost Software License.

```
BOOL noError;
STARTUPINFO startupInfo;
PROCESS_INFORMATION processInformation;
ZeroMemory(&startupInfo, sizeof(startupInfo));
startupInfo.cb = sizeof(startupInfo);
startupInfo.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
startupInfo.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;
noError = CreateProcess(
    NULL,                                           //lpApplicationName
    //Okay the const_cast is bad -- this code was written a while ago.
    //should probably be &commandLine[0] instead. Oh, and commandLine is
    //a std::wstring
    const_cast<LPWSTR>(commandLine.c_str()),        //lpCommandLine
    NULL,                                           //lpProcessAttributes
    NULL,                                           //lpThreadAttributes
    FALSE,                                          //bInheritHandles
    CREATE_NO_WINDOW | CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT,  //dwCreationFlags
    //This is for passing in a custom environment block -- you can probably
    //just use NULL here.
    options.e ? environment : NULL,                 //lpEnvironment
    NULL,                                           //lpCurrentDirectory
    &startupInfo,                                   //lpStartupInfo
    &processInformation                             //lpProcessInformation
);

if(!noError)
{
    return GetLastError();
}

DWORD exitCode = 0;

if (options.w) //Wait
{
    WaitForSingleObject(processInformation.hProcess, INFINITE);
    if (GetExitCodeProcess(processInformation.hProcess, &exitCode) == 0)
    {
        exitCode = (DWORD)-1;
    }
}

CloseHandle( processInformation.hProcess );
CloseHandle( processInformation.hThread );
```

Answer (score 3):

To self-hide already running script you'll need [getCmdPid.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/.net/getCmdPID.bat) and [windowoMode.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/.net/c/windowMode.bat)

```
@echo off

echo self minimizing
call getCmdPid.bat
call windowMode.bat -pid %errorlevel% -mode hidden

echo --other commands--
pause
```

---

**[Here](https://superuser.com/questions/641150/how-to-run-a-process-in-the-background-without-keeping-a-batch-file-open/872858#872858)** I've compiled all ways that I know to start a hidden process with batch without external tools.With a ready to use scripts (some of them  rich on options) , and all of them form command line.Where is possible also the PID is returned .Used tools are IEXPRESS,SCHTASKS,WScript.Shell,Win32_Process and JScript.Net - but all of them wrapped in a `.bat` files.

Answer (score 2):

This little VBScript from [technet](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/ScriptCenter/en-us/8bbed56f-a7aa-491f-a296-687dd96098a3) does the trick:

```
Const HIDDEN_WINDOW = 12

strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set objStartup = objWMIService.Get("Win32_ProcessStartup")

Set objConfig = objStartup.SpawnInstance_
objConfig.ShowWindow = HIDDEN_WINDOW
Set objProcess = GetObject("winmgmts:root\cimv2:Win32_Process")
errReturn = objProcess.Create("mybatch.bat", null, objConfig, intProcessID)
```

Edit `mybatch.bat` to your bat file name, save as a vbs, run it.

Doc says it's not tested in Win7, but I just tested it, it works fine.  Won't show any window for whatever process you run

Answer (score 1):

Create a shortcut to your `bat` file by using the `right-click` and selecting `Create shortcut`.
 `Right-click` on the shortcut you created and click on properties. 
Click on the Run drop-down box and select Minimized.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a windows service that does nothing but execute your batch file.  Since services run in their own desktop session, the command window won't be visible by the user.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Bat To Exe Converter](http://download.cnet.com/Bat-To-Exe-Converter/3000-2069_4-10555897.html) and compile the Bat file as an executable.

Steps:

1. Open Bat to Exe Converter
2. Select your Bat file
3. **In the options select "Invisible Application"**
4. Finish by pressing the compile button

Answer (score -2):

1,Download the bat to exe converter and install it
2,Run the bat to exe application
3,Download .pco images if you want to make good looking exe
4,specify the bat file location(c:\my.bat)
5,Specify the location for saving the exe(ex:c:/my.exe)
6,Select Version Information Tab
7,Choose the icon file (downloaded .pco image)
8,if you want fill the information like version,comapny name etc
9,change the tab to option
10,Select the invisible application(This will hide the command prompt while running the application)
11,Choose 32 bit(if you select 64 bit exe will work only in 32 bit OS)
12,Compile
13,Copy the exe to the location where bat file executed properly
14,Run the exe