# Open application with hidden cmd.exe

Tags: batch-file, cmd, android-virtual-device

To open an Android Virtual Device, I was recommended to add a shortcut or a batch file with the next line:

```
C:\android-sdk\tools\emulator.exe -avd MyAVD
```

Nevertheless, when I do so, this opens with a command line window, which if I close by error (Something frequently since I work with many command line windows for debugging the apps), It also closes the AVD emulator.

I want to open the AVD without the command line window, to prevent this, I was recommended to do so with `cmd /c` or with `start`  at the beginning, but it isn't working either. Anyone can tell me how should I do this?

Comment: `cmd /c "C:\android-sdk\tools\emulator.exe" -avd MyAVD` should work fine in a batch file. What does "it isn't working either" mean exactly? What exactly have you tried (post the batch file content) that "isn't working"?

Comment: Actually I have `cmd /c "C:\android-sdk\tools\emulator.exe -avd MyAVD"`, since it's all part of the same command. Anyway, it doesn't work in either way. I believe it it because the process "Never ends" really when it opens the AVD.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3696515/1665128 for several solutions: commands, scripts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a VBScript to open the command prompt window hidden

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run("C:\batchfile.bat"), 0, True
```

If you save that as `.vbs` and make sure to replace `C:\batchfile.bat` with the location of yours, this will run the command hidden.

Comment: Simple and effective! Thank you. I don't really understand why the ,0,true are doing outside the parenthesis, but it seems to work only in this strange way. Very thankful for this!

Comment: No problem :) I'm not sure why their outside the brackets, but I don't use VB so I never really looked it up!

Answer (score 0):

This should do it, it should run as a subprocess of `taskeng.exe` in Task Manager.

```
schtasks -create -tn foo -tr <command> -sc once -st 00:00 -ru system
schtasks -run -tn foo
schtasks -delete -tn foo -f
```

[**ref**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14391774/schtasks-system-fails)

Comment: Edited: It seems to work only with commands without options, since if I add the full command between quotations marks, I get "ERROR: Access denied", and if I don't, it gives me an "ERROR: Invalid argument/option - -adv". So, it didn't work; to bad, I seemed like a good simple option.