# schtasks SYSTEM fails

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-task-scheduler

It is noted [**here**](https://superuser.com/a/243071) and in the help that you can set "run as".

```
/RU  username      Specifies the "run as" user account (user context)
                       under which the task runs. For the system account,
                       valid values are "", "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"
                       or "SYSTEM".
```

From my tests these commands will start the task

```
schtasks /create /sc once /st 00:00 /f /tr foo.exe /tn bar
schtasks /run /i /tn bar
```

However running it as SYSTEM will not launch `foo.exe`

```
schtasks /create /sc once /st 00:00 /f /tr foo.exe /tn bar /ru SYSTEM
schtasks /run /i /tn bar
```

The reason I would like to run as SYSTEM is because it was said in the other question that doing so would essentially run `foo.exe` in the background without a window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for me

```
C:\Windows\system32>schtasks /create /sc once /st 09:36 /f /tr notepad.exe /tn bar /ru SYSTEM
SUCCESS: The scheduled task "bar" has successfully been created.
```

[image]

It also runs using

```
C:\Windows\system32>schtasks /run /i /tn bar
SUCCESS: Attempted to run the scheduled task "bar".
```

Comment: I get the same success messages from an elevated cmd, but the task refuses to run! Is this because I'm attempting to run a SYSTEM-owned cmd, i.e. my command line is "schtasks /Create /RU "" /SC ONCE /TN systemLogin /TR cmd.exe /ST 00:00"? I've read that you can't do this on Vista and later OSes (I'm on 8.1 Pro), but then why do I get a success message?

Answer (score 1):

You have to run cmd.exe as an administrator then type in your code. Only an administrator can schedule a task to run as SYSTEM and a normal command line doesn't have enough privileges.