# Can I run a GUI program in the background on the windows command-line?

Tags: windows, sharepoint, command-line

I have Richcopy tool which i need to run in every after 5 minutes. I need to the application run in background instead of showing splash window.

Please help us.

Comment: Does the tool have command line options to suppress the splash screen?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps like this

```
schtasks -create -tn <name> -sc minute -mo 5 -tr <command> -ru system
```

[**ref**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14390589)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a VBScript (save as .vbs) to run it hidden in the background

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run("richcopytool.exe"), 0, True
```