# Hiding CMD While Running a Batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

Can we hide Command Prompt when running a Batch file?

Comment: Don't post 2-in-1 questions. Make a second post about `system()`. For batch file, see http://superuser.com/questions/140047/how-to-run-a-batch-file-without-launching-a-command-window

Comment: [This method](https://superuser.com/questions/62525/run-a-completly-hidden-batch-file) works for me, however I also found [this](http://www.mp3car.com/general-mp3car-discussion/55195-how-to-make-a-batch-file-start-hidden-or-minimized.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677773/how-can-i-run-a-windows-batch-file-but-hide-the-command-window) and [this](http://www.ntwind.com/software/hstart.html), [etc, etc...](https://www.google.com.au/#safe=off&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=start+batch+file+hidden.&oq=start+batch+file+hidden.&gs_l=hp.3..0i22i30l4.840.4560.0.4775.24.22.0.2.2.1.

Comment: -1 because you obviously didn't do something as simple as a Google search first.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty confident I like this method the best. Copy and paste the code below into a .vbs file. From there you'll call the batch file... so make sure you edit the last line to specify the path and name of the batch file:

```
Const HIDDEN_WINDOW = 12 

strComputer = "." 
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _ 
& "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2") 
Set objStartup = objWMIService.Get("Win32_ProcessStartup") 

Set objConfig = objStartup.SpawnInstance_ 
objConfig.ShowWindow = HIDDEN_WINDOW 
Set objProcess = GetObject("winmgmts:root\cimv2:Win32_Process") 
errReturn = objProcess.Create("C:\PathOfFile\name.bat", null, objConfig, intProcessID)
```

It definitely worked for me. Comments are welcomed :)