# Cannot run batch file without hiding command window

Tags: vb.net

```
   Dim pi As New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo()
   pi.FileName=(ipchangepath)
   pi.WorkingDirectory=""
   pi.Verb = "RunAs"
   pi.CreateNoWindow = true
   pi.UseShellExecute = False
   Dim p As process=Process.Start(pi) 
   p.WaitForExit
```

I am trying to run a batch file which sets my ip address to a static value. But I cant run the process without hiding the command window because the program won't run if ShellExecute is not true and the Window wont hide if is true.

Any help?

```
netsh interface ip set address name=Wi-Fi source=static addr=10.10.118.161 mask=255.255.254.0 gateway=10.10.116.25 gwmetric=0
netsh interface ip set dns "Wi-Fi" static 10.10.116.5
netsh interface ip add dns "Wi-Fi" 202.200.100.95 index=2
```

The batch file

Answer (score 1):

Try this answer :
[Hide Command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3696515)

OR use this code :

```
Dim process As new Process()
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false
process.StartInfo.FileName = "(ipchangepath)"
process.Start()
```

Answer (score 0):

These two lines will do the trick

```
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true
process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Dim process As new Process()
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false
process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
process.StartInfo.FileName = "(ipchangepath)"
process.Start()
```