# Hide Batch Window?

Tags: batch-file

Made this for a friend and she is complaining that the window shows up and would rather have it be closed.

```
@echo off
title Custom Shutdown
set /P minutes="Enter delay in minutes: "
set /A seconds="%minutes%*60"
echo closing itunes in %minutes% minutes.
timeout %seconds%
taskkill /im itunes.exe
```

Is there anyway I could have it either minimize or hide after accepting user input?

Answer (score 0):

If minimization is an option, just start the `timeout / taskkill` process in a separate, minimized window

```dos
@echo off
    title Custom Shutdown
    set /P "minutes=Enter delay in minutes: "
    set /A "seconds=%minutes%*60"
    echo closing itunes in %minutes% minutes.
    start /min "" cmd /c "timeout %seconds% & taskkill /im itunes.exe"
```

Else, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3696515/2861476) you will find more alternatives