# How do I hide a command window and display all potential errors in an EditBox control?

Tags: c++, c++builder

I am creating simple application in **Borland C++ Builder**.

My code looks like this:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button3Click(TObject *Sender)
{


    system("java -jar decompile.jar -o Source/ file.jar");

}
```

Now I want to hide the command window and show all potential errors in an `EditBox` control. The `EditBox` control should remain empty if there are no errors.

```
Edit1->Text= "ERROR";
```

Comment: Did you consider switching to some more modern and standard compliant C++ implementation? recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) &  [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org) are freely available on most operating systems. And a Linux desktop gives a friendly, free software, environment to learn C++11 (don't bother learning some older obsolete version of C++). Use [Qt](http://qt.io/) to develop GUI applications in C++11

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: what does any of that have to do with the question at hand?  And FWIW, C++Builder's 64bit compiler has always been based on CLang/LLVM, and the latest version of C++Builder just introduced a new 32bit Clang/LLVM-based compiler as well.

Comment: Borland is an old, non C++11 compliant, compiler.

Answer (score 1):

1. **use `TMemo` instead of `TEdit` box for log**

   It have multiple lines and support scrollbars. It is far better for logs.
2. **see [how to redirect commnd promt output to file](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/commandlinereference/a/redirect-command-output-to-file.htm)**

   I do not use JAVA but you can try:

   ```
   system("java -jar decompile.jar -o Source/ file.jar > errorlog.txt");
   ```

   or:

   ```
   system("java -jar decompile.jar -o Source/ file.jar >> errorlog.txt");
   ```

   You can also include the application path

   ```
   AnsiString exepath=ExtractFilePath(Application->ExeName);
   ```

   So you save the file to known location nstead of actual path that could change easily during runtime...
3. **see [How can I run a windows batch file but hide the command window?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3677773/2521214)**

   So you need to use `CreateProcess` with **java.exe** or **command.com** directly. I never done the hiding thing so follow the answer in the linked **Q/A**. If you do not know how to use `CreateProcess` (it can be overwhelming for beginers) then this is how I use it (it does not hide just starts an exe...)

   ```
   STARTUPINFO si;
   PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
   SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES attr0,attr1;

   ZeroMemory(&si,sizeof(si));
   ZeroMemory(&pi,sizeof(pi));
   si.cb=sizeof(si);

   attr0.nLength=sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
   attr0.bInheritHandle=TRUE;
   attr0.lpSecurityDescriptor=NULL;
   attr1=attr0;
   CreateProcess(NULL,"some_app.exe > logfile.txt",&attr0,&attr1,TRUE,NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,NULL,NULL,&si,&pi);
   ```

   And you can use:

   ```
   TerminateProcess(pi.hProcess,0);
   ```

   To force terminate the app ....

**Now when I put all together I got this:**

```
AnsiString s,logfile;
STARTUPINFO si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES attr0,attr1;

ZeroMemory(&si,sizeof(si));
ZeroMemory(&pi,sizeof(pi));
si.cb=sizeof(si);
// hide the process
si.wShowWindow=SW_HIDE;
si.dwFlags=STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;

attr0.nLength=sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
attr0.bInheritHandle=TRUE;
attr0.lpSecurityDescriptor=NULL;
attr1=attr0;

// Application local path log filename
logfile=ExtractFilePath(Application->ExeName)+"logfile.txt";
DeleteFileA(logfile); // delete old log just to be sure
// command line string to run (instead of "dir" use "java -jar decompile.jar -o Source/ file.jar")
s="cmd /c dir > \""+logfile+"\"";

CreateProcess(NULL,s.c_str(),&attr0,&attr1,TRUE,NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,NULL,NULL,&si,&pi);

// wait for execution with some timeout...
for (int i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
    if (FileExists(logfile)) break;
    Sleep(100);
    }
// copy the log into TMemo mm_log ...
if (FileExists(logfile)) mm_log->Lines->LoadFromFile(logfile); else mm_log->Text="No log file found";
```

Where `mm_log` is memo where I copy the log file. This example just run the `dir` command to show directory info... so instead use your JAVA ... as I suggested in rem. If you have older **OS** then instead of `cmd` use `command`. you can also use `FileExists` to determine which one is it ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Win32 `CreateProcess()` function instead of the C `system()` funtion.  `CreateProcess()` allows you to redirect `STDIN`, `STDOUT`, and `STDERR` of the launched process.

[Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499.aspx)

You can launch `java.exe` directly with the desired input parameters, redirecting its output using anonymous pipes created with `CreatePipe()`, and then read output from those pipe using `ReadFile()` until the process terminates.  You can parse and display the output however you want.

As for hiding the command window, when calling `CreateProcess()`, you can either:

1. specify the `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` flag in the `dwCreationFlags` parameter of `CreateProcess()`.
2. in the `STARTUPINFO` structure passed to the `lpStartupInfo` parameter of `CreateProcess()`, include the `STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW` flag in the `STARTUPINFO::dwFlags` field, and set the `STARTUPINFO::wShowWindow` field to `SW_HIDE`.

Try something like this:

```
HANDLE hStdErrRd = NULL;
HANDLE hStdErrWr = NULL;

SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saAttr = {0};
saAttr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES); 
saAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE; 
saAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL; 

if (!CreatePipe(&hStdErrRd, &hStdErrWr, &saAttr, 0)) {
    // error handling
}
if (!SetHandleInformation(hStdErrRd, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0)) {
    // error handling
}

String CmdLine = "\"C:\\path to\\java.exe\" -jar \"C:\\path to\\decompile.jar\" -o Source/ \"C:\\path to\\file.jar\"";

STARTUPINFO si = {0};
si.cb = sizeof(si);
si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES | STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
si.hStdInput = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
si.hStdOutput = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
si.hStdError = hStdErrWr;
si.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;

PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = {0};

if (CreateProcess(NULL, CmdLine.c_str(), NULL, NULL, TRUE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
{
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);

    // must close our handle to the write-side of the pipe so the pipe will close
    // when the child process terminates so ReadFile() will know to stop expecting data...
    CloseHandle(hStdErrWr);

    AnsiString output;
    char buffer[1024];
    DWORD dwBytesRead;

    while (ReadFile(hStdErrRd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), &dwBytesRead, NULL))
    {
        if (dwNumRead == 0)
            break;

        output += AnsiString(buffer, dwBytesRead);
        do
        {
            int pos = output.Pos("\n");
            if (pos == 0)
                break;

            Memo1->Lines->Add(output.SubString(1, pos-1).TrimRight());
            output.Delete(1, pos);
        }
        while (!output.IsEmpty());
    }

    if (!output.IsEmpty())
        Memo1->Lines->Add(output.TrimRight());
}
else
{
    // error handling

    CloseHandle(hStdErrWr);
}

CloseHandle(hStdErrRd);
```