# Does cmd window display when running windows scheduled task as 'user logged on or not'?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, scheduled-tasks, batch-processing, job-scheduling

I am trying to get a scheduled task running a bat file correctly using the windows task scheduler.

When setting the security options to 'Run only when user is logged on', the cmd window displays with the file then running the process.

I want this to run overnight though so want to set it to 'Run whether user is logged on or not' - when running it the cmd window does not display, but the status changes to running (it seems to stay as this status for ever and not complete the process).

My question is should the cmd window display no matter what the security options are set to?

Comment: If you run a task and you aren't logged on, you won't see the cmd window.

Comment: Should I see it if I am logged in and have the security options set to 'Run whether user is logged on or not'?

Comment: As far as I know, if it is not a service, the cmd window will show.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677773/how-can-i-run-a-windows-batch-file-but-hide-the-command-window#3696515 this answer will provide more insight