# Can I run a windows batch file with hidden cmd window but see the programs started by the batch?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, scripting

I want to start a batch file in a hidden way.
[This discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677773/how-can-i-run-a-windows-batch-file-but-hide-the-command-window) describes very well how it can be done: by using the `CreateProcess` API function. Using this method my started batch script is not visible.

The problem is though that the programs (exes) called inside of the batch are hidden, too!

My goal is to **hide** the started batch windows but **show** the windows of the applications called inside the batch.

Is it possible? If so, how? Can I use the `CreateProcess` function for it or do I need another one?

Comment: Could you add the code you use inside the batch-file to start the programs to your question?

Comment: e.g. `helloworld.exe par1 par2`   

  
  The scenario we use is to start the batch, let it make some checks, and then let it start the application helloworld.exe with some input parameters.

Comment: You could try `start cmd /k "helloworld.exe par1 par2"`

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. I also tried with `start "hello-test-title" /WAIT "helloworld.exe"` but also without success.

Comment: You could try executing a program from the batch-file which then uses the same `CreateProcess` to start the new applications in a non-hidden window.

Answer (score 0):

Next *commented* batch script shows possible approach to run *visibly*

- another batch script:

  - `cliParser.bat` simply lists all supplied parameters;
  - `cliParseArg.bat` does the same *and* sets `errorlevel` to parameters count  (zero-based so never returs `0`) by `exit /b %i%`;
- a GUI application: exercised common `calc` and `notepad` executables;
- a Win32 console application: `cliParser.exe` is `cliParser.bat` rewritten in `C++`;

from within an invisible command line window. Examples given how-to run above asynchronously as well as synchronously (i.e. waiting until called app ends).

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions

rem       STDOUT output is invisible if this script runs in a hidden window 
wmic OS get LocalDateTime

rem       another batch script            asynchronously            => visible
start "batch asyn" cmd /K ""D:\bat\cliParser.bat" par1 %* "par 3""

rem errorlevel clear: by virtue of Dave Benham in reply to http://superuser.com/a/649329/376602
(call )
rem       another batch script             synchronously            => visible
start "batch synchr" /WAIT cmd /K "("D:\bat\cliParseArg.bat" par1 %* "par 3"&pause&exit /B %%%%errorlevel%%%%)"
rem `pause` command in above line is merely for debugging purposes to ensure that window is visible 
echo cliParseArg.bat parameter count=%errorlevel%
echo(

rem       a GUI application               asynchronously            => visible
start "" calc.exe

rem       a GUI application                synchronously            => visible
notepad.exe

rem       a console application           asynchronously            => visible
start "CApp asyn" cmd /K ""D:\bat\cliParser.exe" rap1 %* "rap 3""

rem       a console application            synchronously            => visible
start "CApp synchr" /WAIT cmd /K "("D:\bat\cliParser.exe" arg1 %* "arg 3"&exit /B)"

rem       STDOUT output is invisible if this script runs in a hidden window 
cmd /C wmic OS get LocalDateTime
```

Output if called from a visible `cmd` window first and then in a hidden window::

```
==> D:\bat\SO\37181230.bat "xx yy"
LocalDateTime
20160512195221.499000+120

cliParseArg.bat parameter count=4

LocalDateTime
20160512195244.958000+120

==> Wscript D:\VB_scripts\runhidden.vbs "D:\bat\SO\37181230.bat" "A1 B2"

==>
```

The `runhidden.vbs` is adapted from [Rob van der Woude's script](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/files/runnhide_vbs.txt) where

- `strArguments = strArguments & " " & WScript.Arguments(i)` line was changed to
- `strArguments = strArguments & " """ & WScript.Arguments(i) & """"`

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick, use this code in your batch file to start your EXEs.

```
 @echo off
 title GEO-START v2

 REM  #############################################################
 REM ## GEO-START ## starts any file any location with variables. ##
 REM  #############################################################
 REM ##
 REM "start-and-wait-yes-no" variable, Y is yes, N is no. 
 REM ##
 REM "var" variable, "/silent" or "/y". ## The /y variable is grait for "ms self extracting cabinet files" CAB.exe.
 REM ##
 REM "silent" variable, 0 will set the "var" variable to true and trys to run hidden.
 REM "silent" variable, 1 will set the "var" variable to false.
 REM ##
 REM "GEO-START" variable, the name and location of the file you want to start.
 REM ################################################
 set Y=true
 set N=Wscript.Quit
 REM ##############




 REM #####################
 REM ## variables to set ##

 set start-and-wait-yes-no=%Y%
 set var=/silent
 set silent=1
 set GEO-START=Winamp3 v9.1.exe

 echo Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") > GEO-START.vbs && echo WSHShell.Run chr(34) + "%GEO-START%" + chr(34) + " %var%",%silent%,%start-and-wait-yes-no% >> GEO-START.vbs && cscript GEO-START.vbs && del GEO-START.vbs
 Exit
```