# How to hide a command prompt while running a batch file in java

Tags: batch-file

Okay so I am making a game and have fixed most of my problems there is just one thing, the cmd prompt is annoying me when it pops up. If you have any recommendations on how to have the prompts functions run without it opening the prompt itself.

Comment: OH NO          dun dun dun

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I run a windows batch file but hide the command window?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677773/how-can-i-run-a-windows-batch-file-but-hide-the-command-window)

Comment: The external tools [`AutoIt`](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) or [`AutoHotkey`](https://autohotkey.com/) are capable of controlling windows, including hiding them...

Comment: @SomethingDark Yes, you can, just not in pure batch.

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer from @badbod99 for the question [How can I run a windows batch file but hide the command window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677773/how-can-i-run-a-windows-batch-file-but-hide-the-command-window):

```
Const HIDDEN_WINDOW = 12

strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set objStartup = objWMIService.Get("Win32_ProcessStartup")

Set objConfig = objStartup.SpawnInstance_
objConfig.ShowWindow = HIDDEN_WINDOW
Set objProcess = GetObject("winmgmts:root\cimv2:Win32_Process")
errReturn = objProcess.Create("mybatch.bat", null, objConfig, intProcessID)
```

In the last line, change `myfile.bat` to the file location of your batch file. Save this as a .vbs file and run it instead of the batch file.

The batch file part:

```
@echo off
cls
start "" "C:\directory\yourfile.java"
exit
```

Save that as a .bat file. This is the batch file that will be run by the .vbs file.

Comment: Okay I am doing that but it isn't opening my file I wanted it to open the java application without showing me what it is doing. When I run it as a command prompt the command prompt opens then disappears but the jar doesn't run.

Comment: @Azamp19 I edited my answer. Hopefully it will help.

Comment: So when I run the .vbs it does nothing but when I run the batch it shows no text(Jar runs). Oh and if I do the start /b "Directory" it sends me to my code and doesn't run it.

Comment: @Azamp19 You're supposed to change `directory` to the file directory of your file (the folder that it's in) and `yourfile.java` to your java file. When you click on the .vbs it does do stuff, but it's hidden, as you asked it to be.

Comment: Okay so I trust that it does stuff but when I run the vbs I want to see my jar  application but not my cmd prompt.

Comment: @Azamp19 I think I fixed it.

Comment: Okay let me look at it.