# Open files and delete folder with Batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to open docx **(Rough.docx and Ticker.docx)** and delete/copy some folder afterward but batch open first **file (rough)** and stop/wait. following is batch code.

```
"C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\Rough.docx"
"C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\Ticker.docx"

del "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\download\*.*" /q
rd /s /q "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\EMEA CEEMEA"
xcopy "D:\W" "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\" /E
```

what should i include to do all this silently. I mean do not show `CMD`. in VBA something like `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`
I am new in batch programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `start` command.

Assuming you want to open the files with MS Word.

```
start winword.exe "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\Rough.docx"
start winword.exe "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\Ticker.docx"

rd /s /q "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\EMEA CEEMEA"
xcopy "D:\W" "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\" /E
```

If you don't want to open the `CMD` when it starts as a scheduled task you need to call cmd.exe:

```
%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /c PathToYourBATFile
```

If you want start the batch manually by clicking on it, create a shortcut to it and in the properties select `Minimized`.

Comment: what should i include to do all this silently. I mean do not show `CMD`. in VBA something like `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677773/how-can-i-run-a-windows-batch-file-but-hide-the-command-window

Comment: I want to exclude file having name with spaces `CEEMEA & LATAM.doc`. What should I do?  `"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\rar" a -xCEEMEA & LATAM.doc "082917.rar"`. please help

Comment: Maybe it works like this: `"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\rar" a -x"CEEMEA & LATAM.doc" "082917.rar"`? I don't really know WinRAR. I suggest you to ask a new question on superuser.com maybe.

Comment: I had uses `"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\rar" a -x*"ceemea & latam.doc" "082917.rar"` works fine. I dont have reputation on superuser that's why I ask in comments